# Diagonalizable matrices and definition with proofs.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\begin{array}{lll}
> 4. & (a) & \text{Show that if $A$ is similar to $\alpha I$ for some $\alpha$, then $A=\alpha I$.} \\
>    & (b) & \text{Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is an $n$th power, i.e.} \\
>  & & \det(A-tI)=(\alpha-t)^n. \text{Show that $A$ is diagnolizable if and only if $A=\alpha I$.} \\
>    & (c) & \text{Finally, determine for which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the matrix $A=\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & 1}$ is diagonalizable.} \\ 
> \end{array}$

So I realize that this probably isn't that difficult. But I am missing something. I'm having a lot of trouble seeing where to start, especially for part a and b. Any tips or hints would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Have you already studied Jordan Canonical Form?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(a) $\;A\cong \alpha I\implies\;$ they have the same minimal polynomial. But it's easy to see that for $\;\alpha I\;$ this is $\;x-\alpha\;$ .

(b) $\;A\;$ as given is diagonalizable iff its JCF has no $\;1$-s on the first over diagonal iff $\;x-\alpha\;$ is its minimal polynomial iff $\;A=\alpha I\;$ .

(c) $\;A\;$ as given is diagonal iff $\;A\cong 1I=I\iff x-1\;$ is its minimal polynomial iff $\;a=0\;$ (otherwise $\;A-I\neq 0$)

Answer (score 0):

(a) Just write what it means for two matrices to be similar. Then use the fact that a matrix of the form $\alpha I$ commutes with every matrix.

(b) Use the link between the roots of the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues. Then, use the part (a).

(c) Compute the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix. Then use (b).